# Numerical integration of the exact distribution of the product of two random gaussian variables

Tags: r, confidence-interval, numerical-integration

I am trying to implement this function in R, which is equation (2) in this paper by [Cui et al. (2016)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7579552), which is the exact distribution of the product of two random gaussian variables.

```
f <- function(x,rho=0,m1=0,m2=0,s1=1,s2=1,N=10){
  a=rep(0,length(x))
  for(n in 0:N){
    for(m in 0:(2*n)){
      b=(x^(2*n-m)*abs(x)^(m-n)*s1^(m-n-1)) / (pi*factorial(2*n)*(1-rho^2)^(2*n+(1/2))*s2^(m-n+1)) *
        (factorial(2*n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(2*n-m))) * 
        ((m1/s1^2-rho*m2/(s1*s2))^m*(m2/s2^2-rho*m1/(s1*s2))^(2*n-m)) *
        besselK(x=(abs(x)/((1-rho^2)*s1*s2)),nu=(m-n))
      a = a + b
    }
  }
  pdf = exp(-(1/(2*(1-rho^2)))*((m1^2/s1^2)+(m2^2/s2^2)-2*rho*(x+m1*m2)/(s1*s2))) * a 
  return(pdf)
}
```

[image]

I am trying to integrate some portions of this pdf to construct confidence intervals. It works for most cases, especially, if m1=m2=0. However, in numerous instances, the function integrate, cubintegrate (package : cubature), integrale (package : pacma) return errors. My guess is that the error comes from the f(0) which is infinity, but I don't know any workaround. Maybe I transcripted some part of the equation wrong.

Thanks for your help and input!

Comment: Recommend inserting the equation. Some (most?) of us can't read that link.

Comment: Thanks @JTH. I thought the paper was free. I added the equation.

Comment: You have some basic problems to address before trying to integrate this function.  For instance, it appears you are truncating the outer sum at $n=10.$  How do you know this is an adequate approximation?  You also risk overflow and serious loss of precision for certain parameters.  In short, there are basic issues with the coding in evidence.  Start by developing unit tests, especially those that explore extreme cases, to find out where your function fails.

Comment: @Whuber, In Cui et al. (2006), results show that N=10 is pretty good approximation, though they always had $m1$ or $m2$ ($\mu_1,\mu_2)= 0$. There is no example, when both are non-zero.

Comment: Although that may be so, numerical integrators tend to explore extreme and "edge" cases (and, sometimes, they venture beyond the domain of definition of the function and produce warnings, errors, or--worst--incorrect results).  That's why you need thorough testing of your function before using it for numerical integration.  Doing otherwise means you're trying to debug too many things at once, which is an almost impossible task.

Comment: @Whuber Thank you! Increasing $N$, solves some problems (the estimation is much better. However, besselK() seems limited to 50 or so in R, while it seems necessary to increase it even more. Any advices

Comment: There's too much to say: evaluating a function defined like this in a reliable, general, and precise way requires skill and experience with numerical analysis and programming.  I have worked on such code for almost 50 years and even now would avoid implementing this unless I really had to; and if that were the case, I would begin by collecting worked examples, writing unit tests, and analyzing the function's behavior mathematically.  To start, you could work through about half the chapters in [Numerical Recipes](http://www.numerical.recipes/) and study some software engineering techniques.